# Dynamically call class methods with different parameters

Tags: typescript

I want to dynamically call class methods with different names and different parameter interfaces. The provided solution looks like something that I need, and it works if the rule for calling class method defined strictly as const. It refuses to work within the function with unknown parameter. There is definetely some problems with type unions, which I cannot comprehend.

Please, help me fix this code. I want to avoid 'any' and chain of if-s. There are possibly dozens of interfaces, A,B,C,D etc...

```
// Completely different interfaces with different fields
interface A {
    foo: boolean;
}

interface B {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
}


// Operator that processes data, one function = one strictly typed object
class Operator {
    public processA(obj: A) {
        console.log('create');
    }

    public processB(obj: B) {
        console.log('edit');
    }
}


// All operations existing in the Operator, and sets of input for dynamic calls
type Operations = 'processA' | 'processB';

type InputA = {
    operation: 'processA',
    obj: A;
}

type InputB = {
    operation: 'processB',
    obj: B;
}

type Input = InputA | InputB;


// This code works
const action: Input = { operation: 'processB', obj: { bar: 'abc', baz: 1 } }; // concrete action
const operator = new Operator();
operator[action.operation](action.obj); // works with the concrete action variable

// This code doesn't work
function fixHerePlease(action: Input) {
    const operator = new Operator();
    operator[action.operation](action.obj); // doesn't work with action variable as parameter
}
```

This is the error:

`Argument of type 'A | B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'B & A'. Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B & A'. Type 'A' is missing the following properties from type 'B': bar, baz`

Comment: The only reason your first example works is because the compiler is clever enough to narrow `action` to `InputB` on assignment. If you made it a true union (e.g., use `Math.random()` to choose) you'd see the same problem. Your problem is described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the fix is described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), involving generics. See [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/W4JQvN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your example and link gave me some ideas and it solves the original question. It can be used as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, need to remind myself what was going on here.